# Borrowing values from a member variable?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I've sat here for 10 minutes trying to think of the title. If anyone can, feel free to change it.

Anyways, I have two classes `campus` and `building` as well as two arrays in `campus` itself. However those arrays are what I have to use to set the value of `ID` in `building` anyways.

In `campus`, I have `loadFile` and `searchList`

`loadFile` reads from a file, and sets values to three member variables in `building` and the two arrays mentioned earlier.

However I need to use `searchList` to print out those values. (It's an assignment. If I had it my way I'd probably do it differently cause I'm frankly bad at this).

Here's where it all goes downhill. I'm confused with how to proceed. The first thing I tried to do was call the constructor for `building` in `loadFile` which is part of `campus` using `building::building(ID, name, description)` which is supposed to set those values in the constructor itself.

Then in `searchList`, I thought I could go `cout << building::getID() << building::getName() << building::getDescription();` (all of these are member functions in `building`) but obviously through a series of errors I realized this isn't the way to go.

So I tried instead of using the scope resolution operator, I should make a variable of type `building` somewhere. So I made `building a` inside `loadFile` and set `a = building(ID, name, description)` after defining those values.

Of course, this way I can't access `a.getID` in `searchList`. So I tried making it a global variable but obviously it wouldn't be that simple.

If you need more context, [here's](http://docdro.id/QcKHxU1) the assignment details.

Here's my class header

```
int const maxPerBuildingType = 7;
class campus
{
friend class building;
//friend building::building(int, std::string, std::string);


private:
//int academic[maxPerBuildingType]; removed
//int recreation[maxPerBuildingType]; removed
building recreation[maxPerBuildingType];
building academic[maxPerBuildingType]; 
int numberOfAcademic; 
int numberOfRecreation;
std::string temp;
protected:

public:

campus();
static int const maxPerBuildingType;
void loadFile();
void searchList();

};
```

I don't know if you need the definitions since it's wrong anyways but it's [here](https://codeshare.io/isM2e) (updated for edit) if you need it. I'll edit it into this post if necessary.

Anyways guys, thanks.

EDIT: Of course, the answer was because I was stupid. Arrays had to be of type building so i could allocate the required number of buildings. I haven't completed the assignment but for now I believe everything's fine. That'll probably change but eh. Thank you guys!

Comment: When you say you used `building::getID()`, do you mean that, or you used the actual `.` operator for `building b; std::cout << b.getID()`?

Comment: Do you know how classes work and what they do? Once you've defined `building`, you can have *lots of buildings* - so you can't just set building::description or similar, you need to set *a particular building*'s description.

Comment: Think of it like any other data type - why can't I just call `std::string("Hello world")` to set a string and then `std::string::length()` to get its length later, and then `cout << std::string` to print it?

Comment: @immibis I'm fairly new to OOP, and I realized my mistake when it came to that. I was only writing out my thought process, thank you though.

Comment: @Tas I used the `.` operator. I used the scope one earlier but i changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT the moment you are not storing your buildings anywhere. You put them into a local variable called `a` then throw them away.

I suspect the intention of the exercise is to store the buildings into the arrays `academic` and `recreation`. You currently have them as `int` arrays, but possibly they should be arrays of the specific building classes (I assume the exercise also wants you to have different building classes for the types of buildings, probably as a subclass of `Building`).

Once your campus has its own lists of buildings, at lot of your questions will answer themselves naturally.

Comment: The assignment details tell you (in rather painful detail and with lots of typos) how the program should be structured. You need an abstract class called "Building", with two derived classes "Academic" and "Recreation", and a class called "Campus" which is essentially a container (using STL terminology) of "Building". The building classes have accessor methods for extracting their state from private member variables, so you don't need to resort to "friend" and such.

Comment: Hmm, changing them to `building` arrays sounds more reasonable. I guess I was going the long and hard way around. This actually makes a lot more sense. I'll see what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: So when I change them to building, I ran into a few problems but they're fixed. I don't know if it outputs anything yet cause I have two problems. The array in `campus` is claiming the class `building` is undefined AND that the total size of the array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes. I mean it's only holding 7. This issue is true for both `academic` and `recreation` objects of type `building` in class `campus`.

EDIT: i've modified my class in the main post and the link to the other code has also updated. In case you need to see more.

Comment: As the campus class now uses the building class, you need to make sure that building.h is included before you try to declare the campus class. The normal way is to include building.h in campus.h, but then you have to handle the case where it might be included more than once, which might be more advanced than you want. For now, just check that you have building.h included in your cpp files before campus.h

Comment: @TheDark It seems i forgot to include building.h in main. That fixed that. Thank you.