# Accessing a virtual member function from another class[C++]

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

edited the title

I don't know how accurate the title is so...

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305708/borrowing-values-from-a-member-variable) on SO the other day regarding a question of the same assignment but a different and rather simple problem. There's a link to the assignment details there but I hope you wont need them. ([Here](http://docdro.id/QcKHxU1) if it helps though)

Anyways, I have 3 relevant classes. `campus` , `building`, and `recreation` which is a child class of `building`.

In main, I have an object `uni` of type `campus`. For some user choice, I need to pass a value into a virtual function initialized in `building` and defined in `recreation`. Aside from the problem of how do I call that, I'm having trouble defining the virtual function `getFullDescription` to begin with.

Here's the definition of the virtual function in `recreation`

```
 void getFullDescription(int a)
 {
   for (int i = 0; /*campus::recreation[i].ID != a | not valid*/; i++)
   {

   }

 }
```

Here's the header file for campus

```
int const maxPerBuildingType = 7;
class campus
{
friend class building;
//friend building::building(int, std::string, std::string);


private:
building academic[maxPerBuildingType];
building recreation[maxPerBuildingType];
int numberOfAcademic;
int numberOfRecreation;
std::string temp;
protected:

public:

campus();
static int const maxPerBuildingType;
void loadFile();
void searchList();
~campus();

};
```

As you can tell, in the virtual function I have to refer to a class of type 'building' (being `recreation[]`) that was defined in `campus`. I know it's probably simple and basic or whatever but... yeah.

I hope I included all the necessary info. If you need more just say so.

[code for the campus class definitions](https://codeshare.io/isM2e)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? You can't access the `private` member `campus::recreation` from anywhere other than methods of `campus`, even from `friends` like `building`. Try making it protected?

Comment: @twsaef Sorry, I know it's not clear. I'll try to fix that. According to my assignment, it has to be a private data member, though I don't know in what sense of private they mean.

Although, since building is isn't a child, i thought protected would still be private in terms of `building`? And friends should access private data members?

Comment: `private` is only accessible from within the class, `protected` is accessible from within the class, from `friend`s, and from other classes that inherit from that class, and `public` is accessible to everyone.

Comment: @twsaef ok my private members show up when I include the virtual function as a friend (As opposed to including the class itself). However in the function, calling `campus::recreation[i].getID()` is still illegal.

Comment: @twsaef You are mistaken. Friends can too access `private` members. [Demo](http://rextester.com/HTP63931)